# Spectrum of periodic schrödinger operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In many articles it's stated, as if it's common knowledge, that any Schrödinger operator with periodic potenial has purely absolutely continuous spectrum. I've tried to actually find a theorem stateting this with no luck. I've looking in Reed and simon, Teschl and googled endlessly. I can't seem to find any theorem which states this is true in the case of a one dimensional periodic potential?

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it Thm. XIII.90 p. 297, Vol. 4 of Reed & Simon?

Comment: I also had trouble Googling it. It could well be that nobody other than the intrepid R&S have written out the  entire proof in one place. I don't think I could usefully summarize the 20 page proof in an Answer.